# Delete file using impersonation - access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, admin, delete-file, impersonation, revit

I'm creating Revit add-in, the add-in deletes files from `C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2017` folder on Revit startup.
I'm using impersonation to copy, rename and delete files using the admin credentials.

The problem is when I start the Revit as administrator, it works perfectly. but when starting normally, it won't work and throws this `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.`

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: If it's ok for your application to always run as administrator then have a search for how to run your application as an administrator (somebody has posted below).  Otherwise, I'm afraid you don't have permission to access this

Comment: I need to delete files located in that directory, but I don't want to start Revit as admin because users of Revit don't have admin privileges.

Comment: check out System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission. You might get around it if you "permission.Demand()" FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess. You'll need to get a FileInfo for each file in the directory, and demand each one.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

Add into your project Application Manifest File (Add -> New Item -> General -> Application Manifest File) and add the below node into the app.manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx